# Including additional custom attributes in an laravel eloquent response

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Model

```
class Profile extends Eloquent {

     public function user(){ return $this->belongsTo('User'); }

     public function url(){
        return URL::Route('profile', array('city_slug' => $this->city_slug, 'slug'=> $this->slug));
     }

}
```

Controller

```
class ProfileController extends BaseController {
    public function show($user_id)
    {
         $profile = Profile::with('user')->where('user_id', $user_id);
         return Response::json($profile, 200);
    }
}
```

I would like the response to include the generated URL from the Profile method url(){}

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "url" : /profile/{city_slug}/{slug},
    ....
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may need to create a new array, and append the model object, and the additional url and JSON-ify that. Perhaps do that as a function in the model class?

Comment: @CollinHenderson - that is what I've been doing. I was hoping I could be a bit cleverer and do something like `$profile = Profile::with('url', 'user')->where('user_id', $user_id);`

Answer (score 0):

I would go at this the other way.

In your Users model...

```
public function profile()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Profiles','profile_id');
}
```

Then you can use `$profile = User::find(user_id)->profile`.

```
$data = array(
    'id' => $profile->id,
    'url' => "/profile/".$profile->city_slug."/".profile->slug
);
```

And then finally
`return Repsonse::json($data,200);`